# Servidor apache slave

Tags: linux, apache, http, servidor

A dúvida é bem simples, portanto desculpe -me pela ignorância. Estou montando um website com o apache e o mesmo vai receber  milhares de acesso, a dúvida seria, o que fazer quando o limite de acesso do apache se esgotar? Existe alguma forma de colocar servidores simultâneos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando assim você tem que criar um cluster.

## O que é um cluster?

Um cluster de computador é um conjunto de computadores conectados que trabalham juntos para que, em muitos aspectos, possam ser vistos como um único sistema. Ao contrário dos computadores conectados simplesmente em rede onde os computadores se comportam como vários indivíduos, os clusters de computadores têm cada nó(máquina) configurado para executar a mesma tarefa, controlada e programada pelo software o que faz com que todos ajam como um.

Os componentes de um cluster são normalmente conectados uns aos outros através de redes locais rápidas, com cada nó (computador usado como servidor) executando sua própria instância de um sistema operacional. Na maioria das circunstâncias, todos os nós usam o mesmo hardware, Cluster [Beowulf](https://beowulf.org/overview/faq.html).

Para lhe informar os detalhes de como fazer o cluster preciso saber o OS, pois só informar Linux não é o suficiente pois nem todos os Linux podem ser diretamente clusteados portanto precisando de software especializado, normalmente infraestrutura para softwares de MPI(Message Passing Interface).

## Tipos de clusters:

- Cluster de Alto Desempenho: denominado, também, de Alta Performance (High Performance Computing - HPC), sua característica é o grande volume de processamento de dados em computadores convencionais, que garante baixo custo na construção, e com processamento na ordem de gigaflops. Os servidores deste cluster trabalham com a tecnologia de paralelismo, dividindo o processamento com as outras máquinas, buscando a otimização e desempenho de um supercomputador.
- Cluster de Alta Disponibilidade (High Availability - HA): são caracterizados por se manterem em pleno funcionamento por um longo período de tempo, utilizando redundância para manter um serviço ativo e se proteger de falhas, geralmente são computadores convencionais que disponibilizam o mesmo recurso em todas as máquinas da rede, configuradas com prioridades diferentes, onde existe um servidor ativo e os outros ociosos.
- Cluster de Balanceamento de Carga (Horizontal Scaling - HS): são caracterizados por dividirem, de forma equilibrada, as tarefas entre os membros do cluster, onde cada nó atenda a uma requisição e não, necessariamente, que divida uma tarefa com outras máquinas.

## Solução:

Como já escrevi cada sistema tem suas particularidades. Então para para você ter uma noção [aqui tem um tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-a-loadbalanced-ha-apache-cluster-ubuntu8.04) de como criar um cluster de Balanceamento de Carga no Ubuntu com servidor Apache. É um tutorial de duas páginas. Não é difícil de segui-lo porém é trabalhoso.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode implementar um load balancer para dividir as requisições em mais servidores, pode usar também um servidor de cache intermediário para diminui as conexões com o apache.

Att.